# Can Sublime Text 2 automatically add HTML tags when pasting plain text?

Tags: html, sublimetext2

So I have a text file containing numerous paragraphs and bolded lines. I'm wondering if there's a plugin that I can use in Sublime Text 2 that will automatically add the < p > < /p > tags for the paragraphs as well as < h4 >< /h4 > tags for the bolded lines when I copy/paste all the texts into ST2?

This will make things much easier since I have several text files to update.

Comment: how does a text file have bolded lines?

Comment: Sorry, to reiterate, bolded texts.

Answer (score 0):

I would use snippets.

Here is an example of one you might do for the "bold text":

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<h4>${1:boldtext}</h4>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>boldtext</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

**To install:**

1. Menu -> Tools -> New Snippet
2. Paste the above code, save.

**To use:**

1. Type the word **boldtext** and press `Tab`
2. Paste your text in the already selected area

Then just make another snippet file for each type of "paste" you want to do.